# How to call Web API from ExtJS with token based authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, extjs, access-token

Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'Employee/Search',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { "Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json","Authorization": "OAuth oauth_token=158ghhBtgf2586525hggfgdf" },
                jsonData: {
                    "FirstName": txtFirstName.getValue()
                },
                 success: function(response) {
                },
                 failure: function(response) {
                }
});

This is giving me 401 (Unauthorized Request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `adal.js` library by Microsoft, and using the following code:

```
window.acquireTokenCallback = function (error, token) {
    if(error || !token) {
        Ext.alert('ADALERROR', error || 'Token empty');
        return;
    }
    // Apply token to all future Ajax requests.
    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    });
    // Load Settings from Server.
    me.loadSettings();
};
```